# Converting an integer into a string array and outputting it

Tags: javascript

I want to change my input an Integer into a String array. I used javascript to write such a function but unfortunately it doesnt work. I tried everything i know but i have no clue what i did wrong. Would appreciate some help/explanations etc. Here is the code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function convert() {
        var umge = document.getElementbyId('eingabe').value;
        if(umge == 0005010) {
            var aus = {"Maria", "Nord", "1a", "VS Langenzersdorf"};
            var myJSON = JSON.stringify(aus);
            document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = myJSON;
            document.getElementById('input').innerHTML = "";
        }
    }

</script>



</head>
<body bgcolor="orange">
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="text" name="input" id="input" value="0005010"> 
<input type="submit" value="Umwandeln" onclick="convert();"> 

<p name="output" id="output"> Kein Wert</p>


</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementbyId` - `getElementById`.

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: `aus` should be `aus = [ ... ]` not `aus = { ... }`.

Comment: As well as the typo with `getElementById`, you refer to an element that doesn't exist, `eingabe` - JavaScript doesn't convert that to the English `input`(which is the element you seem to want) automatically :)

Comment: "_change my input an Integer into a String array .. I tried everything i know_" I don't see where you are trying to covert numbers to strings at all.

Comment: I made those changes. But there is no difference neither the browser console is showing any error.

Comment: Your browser console should show you `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ,` for the line with `var aus = ...`, so you should find out why you are not seeing that in your environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other than the problems mentioned in the comments, your declaration of `aus` is wrong: an object should be `{k1:"v2"}` and an array should be `["v1","v2"]`.

Also, your input box is type `text`, so its `value` is a string, not a number, so you need to compare it to a string. I cleaned up your code into something runnable here : https://plnkr.co/edit/Sny3LuBDGh0ZKHY0lSWx?p=preview

---

Basically you should either do this :

```
var umge = document.getElementById('input').value;
if(umge == "0005010") { .... }
```

Or something like this :

```
var umge = parseInt(document.getElementById('input').value);
if(umge == 5010) { .... } // note - no leading 0s!
```

Comment: Im feeling dumb right now. That solves the problem i had with it. Thanks for the answer. :)